# custom meta field in taxonomy media up loader button no working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have added a meta field to upload image in custom taxonomy. It has a problem that image is not uploading.

```
    function product_categories_custom_fields($tag)
    {
        // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing
        $t_id = $tag->term_id; 
        // Get the ID of the term you're editing
        $term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_$t_id"); // Do the check

    ?>

   <tr class="form-field">
   <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Product            Category Banner URL'); ?></label></th>
   <td>
   <input id="banner-url" name="term_meta[banner]" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['banner'] ? $term_meta['banner'] : ''; ?>" name="image" />
   <input id="banner-button" field-id="banner-url" type="button" class="upload button" value="Upload Image" /><br />
   <span class="description"><?php _e('Upload Product Banner Image (Resolution: 1920x550)'); ?></span>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="form-field">
   <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Product Category Image URL'); ?></label></th>
   <td>
   <input id="image-url" name="term_meta[img]" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['img'] ? $term_meta['img'] : ''; ?>" name="image" />
   <input id="upload-button" field-id="image-url" type="button" class="upload button" value="Upload Image" /><br />
   <span class="description"><?php _e('Upload Product Category Image (Resolution: 370x370)'); ?></span>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="form-field">
   <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_sort_order"><?php _e('Product Sort Order'); ?></label></th>
   <td>
   <input id="banner-url" name="term_meta[sort_order]" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['sort_order'] ? $term_meta['sort_order'] : ''; ?>" />
   <span class="description"><?php _e('&nbsp;'); ?></span>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

**javascript file after this in the same file is**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var mediaUploader;
window.field_id = '';

$('.upload').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.field_id = $(this).attr('field-id');
// If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
  if (mediaUploader) {
    mediaUploader.open();
  return;
}
// Extend the wp.media object
mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
  title: 'Choose Image',
  button: {
  text: 'Choose Image'
}, multiple: false });

// When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
  attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
  $('#'+window.field_id).val(attachment.url);
 });
   // Open the uploader dialog
   mediaUploader.open();
  });

  });
 </script>
```

**After this function and for hooking**
i have then made a function to use this

```
  function save_product_categories_custom_fields($term_id)
  {
  if (isset($_POST['term_meta'])) {
    $t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_$t_id");
    $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
    foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
        if (isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])) {
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
    //save the option array
    update_option("taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta);
   }
 }
add_action('product_categories_edit_form_fields', 'product_categories_custom_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('edited_product_categories', 'save_product_categories_custom_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('product_categories_add_form_fields', 'product_categories_custom_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('create_product_categories', 'save_product_categories_custom_fields', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Where is your `wp_enqueue_media();` ?

Comment: i havent any idea about that..

Comment: A [neat tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-media-uploader--cms-22011) about media uploader, maybe it could help.

Comment: how should i add it..kindly if you can tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to enqueue your javascript files:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_media();
   wp_enqueue_script('admin-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), false); 
}
```

Now if you're in your theme, then the path to your `admin.js` script should be something like

```
get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/admin.js'
```

The first code is if you're creating a plugin. The `admin.js` file is the one with the javascript you've written above.

Now you just need to hook this function to `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

This should be it. If you inspect, on your page the scripts loaded, `admin.js` should be among them, along with the media upload scripts.

Comment: their is no admin.js file in my theme

Comment: Well create it and add the code with your javascript in it.

Comment: this js code which i have used here..or it will be some other

Comment: The one here, that triggers the click event. Remove it from the file it is currently in (you said the same file), and add it in `admin.js` file.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403  it is showing this error. i have cut the script code from here and make new file admin.js and paste code their

Comment: Is this in your theme, or your plugin?

Comment: it is in my theme...inside js folder

Comment: And are you using `get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/admin.js'` in `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: 'admin-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), false i have used this

Comment: That's why it wasn't working. If your files are in the theme, and your js file is in the theme as well, you should be using the `get_template_directory_uri()` code...

Comment: Can you post the error it gives? The code should look like: `wp_enqueue_script('admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), false);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106556/discussion-between-waqas-jr-developer-and-dingo-d).